# Kotlin Boolean return function

Tags: function, kotlin, boolean, boolean-expression

I did some research on `Boolean` return type function and I found that it's safer to use with a nullable check.

Now the compiler doesn't like what I did.

I also tried with if statement and it somehow returns only false.

Can anyone please explain this to me!

```
fun check(list:ArrayList<String>): Boolean {
    var test: Boolean?= null
    
    for (i in list) {
        when (i=="a") {
            true -> test == true
            false -> test == false
        }
    }
    return test!!
}
```

Comment: Woahs what's up with the `when` statement?

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `list.any { it == "a" }`.

Answer (score 7):

Since this function only returns a true or false, you shouldn’t be making the variable `test` nullable. But the compiler will complain if you remove the `?` and the `= null` because it can’t guarantee the code in your for loop will ever be called (because the list could be empty).

As for why it’s giving you the wrong result, it’s because you’re changing the value of `test` for every item in the list, so the final value depends only on the last element in the list. Also, if the list is empty, `test` will remain null and you’ll get an exception when you use `test!!`.

I don’t know if you’re trying to see if *any* element of the list is “a” or if *all* elements are “a”, but for the sake of discussion I’ll assume it is the first one. So the strategy here is to make false the default, and change it to true if you find any elements that are “a”.  And once you find one, there’s no reason to keep checking so you can break out of the loop.

```
var test = false // not nullable
for (i in list)
    if (i == "a") {
        test = true
        break
    }
return test
```

As a side note, Kotlin has a higher-order function for List that checks for any element that satisfies the lambda so the above code could be replaced with

```
return list.any { it == "a" }
```

Another side note: if you are setting a Boolean based on some criteria, a when statement is overkill and makes your code more complicated. You could have replaced your when statement with `test = i == "a"` and had equivalent behavior (although as you found, it wasn’t right behavior to begin with).

Comment: Further code improvements would be to make it an extension function, and make the type more general; then the whole thing becomes just `fun Iterable<String>.check() = any{ it == "a" }`.